# Running JavaFX programs gives error messages

Tags: programming

I've created JavaFX programs with IntelliJIDEA on Freya, and everytime I run them, I get these warning messages:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

(java:2818): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(java:2818): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(java:2818): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(java:2818): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(java:2818): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

So far, they're harmless, and everything works, but I'd like to fix them, just for good measure. I've posted this question here, because it's related to Pantheon, and therefore, elementary OS itself.

Comment: Happens with Android Studio too